# Pulling out only fasta sequences python

Tags: python, fasta

I want to read in a large file that contains the fasta sequences (1 header and 1 line of sequence below the header) and other random junk and unorganized spacing in between lines.

I want to read each line in and if a line starts with the ">" symbol, which is how a fasta sequence header starts, then pull that header out along with the next line which would be the sequence.

I have a small example data file to show:

```
> 1
GCTAGCGCCACCatgactcccgcatttatcttgtgcatgctctt
>2
GCTAGCACCATGGAGACAGACACACTCCTGCTATGGGTACTGCTGCTCTG
>3
GCTAGCACCATGGAGACAGACACACTCCTGCTATG


Task 2: Subclone the synthesized

junk 

junk

>4
GCTAGCACCATGGAGACAGAC
```

my code:

```
f=open("File.fasta", "r")
fastaseq = open("OnlyFastaseq.fasta", "w")

for line in f:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    if line.startswith(">"):
        title = line.rstrip()
        seq = f.readline()
        seq = seq.rstrip()
        fastaseq.write(title+"\n"+seq+"\n")
```

**desired output:**

```
> 1
GCTAGCGCCACCatgactcccgcatttatcttgtgcatgctctt
>2
GCTAGCACCATGGAGACAGACACACTCCTGCTATGGGTACTGCTGCTCTG
>3
GCTAGCACCATGGAGACAGACACACTCCTGCTATG
>4
GCTAGCACCATGGAGACAGAC
```

the result contains most of the header+sequence except for the '>3' sequence, it **didn't pull the next line** (which is the sequence) out.

```
> 1
GCTAGCGCCACCatgactcccgcatttatcttgtgcatgctctt
>2
GCTAGCACCATGGAGACAGACACACTCCTGCTATGGGTACTGCTGCTCTG
>3
>4
GCTAGCACCATGGAGACAGAC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter those out by iterating over the input and finding the lines that start with `>` then write that line and the `next` from from the input file, eg:

```
with open('File.fasta') as fin, open('OnlyFastaseq.fasta', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            fout.write(line)
            fout.write(next(fin))
```

Comment: Small caveat: FASTA sequences are often divided in lines of 80 nucleotides/amino acids and can therefore have multiple lines with sequences. In this particular case the code will work perfectly fine, for longer sequences it might return partial sequences.

Comment: @Ashafix interesting - thanks for that. If it comes up as an issue I'm sure I can amend the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try [BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Biopython).  It can certainly be done with 'open' and some parsing, but BioPython has loads of other functionality.  To read one sequence at a time you could use.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
fastaFile = "foo.fasta"
handle = open(fastaFile,"r")
for record in SeqIO.parse(handle,"fasta"):
    print record.id
handle.close()
```

See the [SeqIO docs](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO) for more details.

Comment: I was going to suggest biopython (and I'm fairly sure I've come across these sorts of questions before) - I just wasn't sure if it'd through a wobbly if the file wasn't already fasta format... (ie - it'd successfully ignore the junk the OP has suggested may be in the file)

Comment: Not sure it would ignore junk either.  I would probably separate the two tasks.  (1) parse the junk out first and save a new clean file and then (2) read the fasta sequences.  lines can easily be checked with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give the desired output. It only prints headers starting with `>` and valid sequences, i.e. only ATGC.

```
f = open("File.fasta", "r")

for line in f:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    if line.startswith(">"):
        title = line.strip()
        print(title)
    else:
        seq = line.strip().upper()
        if 0 not in [c in 'ATGC' for c in seq]:
            print(seq)
```

Comment: Consider what happens when there are 3 lines, the first having the ">" identifier, the 2nd being a desired sequence and the third line simply being "CATG". Your code would print out that third line too. It would also not print a correct line that misses one of the letters (a sequence of "ATTA" can occur).

Comment: The specification of the FASTA format is a header which starts with > followed by line(s) of sequences. So the 3rd line should be printed as well. Thanks for pointing out the possibility of only having a subset of nucleotides. I'll change the answer accordingly.